# How to Use my Windows 10 as a Proxy Server

Tags: windows, proxy

This should be an easy question already answered somewhere but when I try to search for this topic it's overlapping with "setting a proxy on windows".

What I am trying to accomplish is use the internet connexion from one or more windows computers through a proxy (preferably using a username and password)

The windows computers are connecting to the internet through a wifi.

Bottomline, I want to end up with an ip:username:password so I can connect through them and I know I can also do that by setting a vpn but I prefer a proxy.

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Setup an actual proxy software on your box (e.g. squid) and configure your clients to use it.

Comment: @Seth I've successfully installed Squid on my windows machine but not sure how should I configure to accomplish my target (have a public ip:user:password) that I can connect externally.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Authentication) that's available for it? [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297196/how-to-set-up-a-squid-proxy-with-basic-username-and-password-authentication) seems to have an answer. If you want to it to be able to be accessed from an external client you will probably have to setup some kind of port forwarding for it (dependent on your ISP and home network setup).